# Refractometer correction for cider making

Tags: cider, gravity-reading, refractometer

I have a refractometer for measuring my OG and FG for my home brews. Eventually, I found out about [wort correction](https://www.brewersfriend.com/refractometer-calculator/). Are cider and wort too different to use the same correction tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the same wort calculators on ciders with some success.  True the ingredients are different, but the correction curves should be similar.  Personally for beer-wort I use a correction factor of 0.99 for my refractometer, and 1.04 for cider... but your mileage may vary.  You might even find the opposite is true for your refractometer.  Each gauge has its own uniqueness that takes dozens of batches to figure out, and I'll admit I am not quite there yet.  But yes, overall, I think it is wise to use the same correction calculators, with the understanding that it might be pretty far off until you gain enough experience over many batches to understand your own correction factor, and the limitations of the equations which don't always work very well above say an OG of 1.090 or whatever.